# How can I put individual "p" elements into the "container" div using js function?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to put "p" elements() into the "div"(container) elements but failed  -->

```
let t = [
    "First line!",
    "Second line!",
    "Third line!",
    "Fourth line!"
];

let T = t.length;

function load(){
    for(let i = 0; i < T; i++){
        let contElem = document.createElement("div");
        contElem.setAttribute("class", "container");
        contElem.setAttribute("onload", "load02()");
        document.querySelector("#main").appendChild(contElem);
    }
}

function load02(){
    for(let i = 0; i < T; i++){
        let myElem = document.createElement("p");
        myElem.innerHTML = t[i];
        document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(myElem);
    }
}
```

but it did not work! Help!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "it did not work!" What *did* happen? How/when are you calling `load()` and `load02()`? It seemed to work correctly for me.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(myElem);` will always append myElem to the first container on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You're attribute `onload` will never fire ...  Since the DOM has already "loaded" at this point ..   You just need to call the function .. And call `load2()` at the end of function 1

```js
let t = [
    "First line!",
    "Second line!",
    "Third line!",
    "Fourth line!"
];

let T = t.length;
load();  // RUN YOUR FUNCTION
function load(){
    for(let i = 0; i < T; i++){
        let contElem = document.createElement("div");
        contElem.setAttribute("class", "container");
        //contElem.setAttribute("onload", "load2()"); // REMOVE THIS
        document.querySelector("#main").appendChild(contElem);
    }
    load2();  //ADD THIS
}

function load2(){
    for(let i = 0; i < T; i++){
        let myElem = document.createElement("p");
        myElem.innerHTML = t[i];
        document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(myElem);
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid #FF0000;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Comment: If he really wanted to use two functions and place each p in a seperate div change `document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(myElem);` to `document.querySelectorAll(".container")[i].appendChild(myElem);`

Answer (score -1):

```js
let t = [
  "First line!",
  "Second line!",
  "Third line!",
  "Fourth line!"
];

let T = t.length;

function load() {
  for (let i = 0; i < T; i++) {
    let contElem = document.createElement("div"), myElem = document.createElement("p");
    contElem.setAttribute("class", "container");
    myElem.innerHTML = t[i];
    contElem.appendChild(myElem);
    document.querySelector("#main").appendChild(contElem);
  }
}

load();
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Does that work? Or were you wanting to put all four p elements in each containing div element?